# Class php для форматирования json

Tags: php, json

Существует ли класс php для красивого форматирования JSON строки? Json получается очень большой и если записать в файл одной строкой, то будет плохо читаемый.

Comment: json_decode не вариант?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov а как я запишу в файл если сделаю json_decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если json уже представлен строкой

то можно

```
json_encode(json_decode($json, true), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```

Если это массив то просто

```
json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```

Ну а дальше пишем в файл и все будет красиво.

Comment: Спасибо, только теперь возникла проблема с кириллицей. Куда вставить JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE что бы кириллица поддерживалась?

Comment: Допускаеться вот так json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)

Comment: Спасибо за профессионализм

Answer (score 1):

Можно перевести массив в JSON со всеми отступами с помощью константы [JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php)

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```

Если на входе у вас уже JSON строка то перед этим переведите ее в массив.

```
json_encode(json_decode($string), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```